# Show linked file elements in forge viewer master view

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-bim360

I uploaded revit linked files to Bim360. After uploading, in the 3d view of the central file which I public in Revit, I can see elements that come from linked files. But in master view, I do not see them. Is that possible that the master view can have linked files' elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to view linked contents in master views (or called Phase views) generated by Model Derivative, according to https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST

> generateMasterViews bool Generates master views when translating from
> the Revit input format to SVF. This option is ignored for all other
> input formats. This attribute defaults to false.
>
> Master views are 3D views that are generated for each phase of the
> Revit model. A master view contains all elements (including “room”
> elements) present in the host model for that phase. The display name
> of a master view defaults to the name of the phase it is generated
> from. However, if a view with that name already exists, the Model
> Derivative service appends a suffix to the default display name.
>
> Notes:
>
> 1. Master views do not contain elements from linked models.
> 2. Enabling this option can increase the time it takes to translate the model.

Comment: I have another question about this topic too, could you take a look? Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76751353/how-to-distinguish-elements-of-file-central-and-file-linked-on-forge-viewer

Answer (score 0):

When you say the "master view" I assume you are simply referring to another model view. Most likely there is some difference in the visibility/graphics settings between the two views.

One of the easiest ways to eliminate this factor is:

1. Open the view where you can see the links
2. Go to the View tab > Graphics panel > View Templates dropdown > Create Template from Current View
3. Enter something like "temporary view template" and hit OK
4. Go to the view where you cannot see the links
5. Assign your newly created View Template to the view

This is simplest if both views are the same kind of view (eg 3D Views). You can assign a 3D View Template to non-3D Views but it might not behave the same.