# How to distinguish elements of file central and file linked on Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, revit-api, autodesk-model-derivative

I uploaded linked files to bim360 and use Forge to view the central file. I want to distinguish elements of file central and file linked, any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's possible to achieve this request. We can leverage the AecModelData to get linked model data and rebuild relationships from the PropertyDB inside APS Viewer.

```js
// Get linked documents data 
let model = viewer.getAllModels()[0];
const aecData = await Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getAecModelData(model.getDocumentNode());
let rvtLinks = aecData.linkedDocuments;

// Get linked elements of given link instance id
function getExternalIdMappingAsync( model ) {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        model.getExternalIdMapping(
            map => resolve( map ),
            error => reject( error )
        );
    });
}

let instanceId = rvtLinks[0].instanceId;
let model = viewer.getAllModels()[0];
let externalIdMap = await getExternalIdMappingAsync( model );
let entities = Object.entries(externalIdMap);
let linkedElementIds = rvtLinkExternalIds.map(instanceId => {
                return entities.filter(entity => entity[0].includes(`${instanceId}/`)).map(entity => entity[1]);
})
  .flat();
```

You can find more details here:

[image]

References:

- [How can i get the list of link files from a translated compressed/zip of revit file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64661353/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-link-files-from-a-translated-compressed-zip-of-revit-f)
- https://youtu.be/nfHZLlWtQ-0?t=111
- https://github.com/yiskang/au-2021-forge-lightning-talk-sample/blob/main/server/www/js/revit-link-relp.js